# Cannot read property 'function' of undefined using this.function (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I have been researching this topic for a while and am completely stuck. I am using `React.js`, and using an es6 class component.

When I call `this.showDate` inside of my `filterCourses` function it is claiming that it can't read the `showDate` property of `undefined`. This means the keyword `this` is `undefined`.

I have tried binding `this` in the constructor.

**Question**

How do I make `this` defined?

---

```
class Upcoming_Training extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {}
  showDate(date) {
    // Creates a more readable date
    if (date) {
      date = date.substring(0, date.indexOf("T"));
      let dateArr = date.split('-');
      return dateArr[1] + '/' + dateArr[2] + '/' + dateArr[0];
    }
  }
  filterCourses() {
    let courseRows = [];
    if (this.props.upcoming_training != []) {
      if (this.showDate) {
        let courseRows = this.props.upcoming_training.map(function (
          course, index) {
          return <tr>
                   <th><button className='btn btn-sm btn-primary'> More Info </button></th> {/*Will make this button do something later*/}
                   <td>{course.Course}</td>
                   <td> {(course.Name.includes("OL -") ? course.Name.slice(5) : course.Name)}</td>
                   <td>{this.showDate(course.Start)}</td>
                   <td>{this.showDate(course.End)}</td>
                   <td>{(course.IsOnline ? "Online" : "On-Site")}</td>
                 </tr>
        })
      }
      return courseRows;
    }
    return [];
  }
```

Comment: You've already tried adding `this.filterCourses = this.filterCourses.bind(this)` to your constructor?

Comment: yes I added this.filterCourses = this.filterCourses.bind(this) and this.showDate = this.showDate.bind(this)  **I dont really understand what this is doing from a fundamental level, so if doing it to both is a problem then I didnt know.

But just doing the this.filterCourses on it's own did not work either.

Comment: You only need to bind functions that are using the `this` keyword. So you would need it in `filterCourses`, but not in `showData`, since you never use `this` in that function.

Comment: Thanks for that bit of info Trevor! :)

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think an issue might be that you are passing a function to `this.props.upcoming_training.map`, That map as defined in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map takes a `thisArg` and since you are not providing one it will be `undefined`. That causes the `this` in `this.showDate` to be `undefined`. Either binding `showDate` or providing a thisArg should aleviate the problem.

Comment: That worked Emil, thank you!  I just added a ,this after the callback function.  I have never used the second argument in map before!  Thank you so much, that was 3 hours of being stuck haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Emil H mentioned in the comments above, the issue is that `this` is not bound once you enter the `map` function. You can either pass the `thisArg` to the map function, or move that function to a separate class function that you bind in your constructor. That would look something like this (untested):

```
class Upcoming_Training extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.filterCourses = this.filterCourses.bind(this);
    this.renderCourseRow = this.renderCourseRow.bind(this);
  }

  showDate(date) {
    // Format date...
  }

  renderCourseRow(course, index) {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <th><button className='btn btn-sm btn-primary'> More Info </button></th>
        <td>{course.Course}</td>
        <td>{(course.Name.includes("OL -") ? course.Name.slice(5) : course.Name)}</td>
        <td>{this.showDate(course.Start)}</td>
        <td>{this.showDate(course.End)}</td>
        <td>{(course.IsOnline ? "Online" : "On-Site")}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }

  filterCourses() {
    if (this.props.upcoming_training != []) {
      return this.props.upcoming_training.map(renderCourseRow);
    }
    return [];
  }

  // ...Rest of component
}
```

Comment: Arrow function also could have worked.  I was so use to writing keyword function due to IE compatibility, but create-react-app allows arrow functions to be converted.  Which is awesome.

Answer (score -1):

First remove comma after `inputValue: '',` in the this.state declaration. Also in your filterCourses function the `if(this.showDate)` condition is looking for a showDate property not a function. You function showDate also expects a date.

You also need a render function as any react component is required to have one.

Comment: I have a render function, I just did not put it in the code snippet as it was not relevant to the error.  I only added that if condition after the fact that this error started happening, so even without it, the error is there.